# Linux client request certificates from windows NPS server

Tags: linux, windows, server, windows-server-2008, client-certificates

I am setting up EAP-TLS authentication using the manual https://networklessons.com/wireless/peap-and-eap-tls-on-server-2008-and-cisco-wlc/.

My server and client details are below:

Server: NPS 2008

Client: Linux

I generated the server certificates on the NPS server as well as the CA cert. I imported the CA cert to the Linux server but after this the manual I am using tells me to log into the IP of server using a web browser and request client certificate from there.This is the part I am stuck in.

I tried curl -k https://< ip of server > but this returned an error:

curl:(7) couldn't connect to host error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Update: I generated server, client and CA certificates on client side(linux) using openssl and the combined the CA, server cert and server key into a .pfx file and imported this onto the NPS server using MMC. But the connection is stuck as "Associating". From wireshark capture I see that the server sends an access reject to the controller(WLC). Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked:

- httpd is running on the server
- httpd is listening for TCP on port 443 (I like ProcessMonitor from MS for this)
- https://localhost/ access from the NPS server (to itself) works as expected
- firewall on the server is shut down or is allowing https access on the correct
  network interface
- https://ip_address/ access from the NPS server (to
  itself) works as expected
- https access works from another client on
  the same LAN segment

Comment: Daniel I am able to set up PEAP-MsCHAP , so the things mentioned by you on the server side are good. When I tried https://ip_address_server/ from the server, it opens up a IIS7 Internet information services page.

Comment: It sounds like a firewall issue to me, Sid.  If you can get to https://ip_address/ from the server but not from a client, then either client can't get to the server because of a networking issue--which is probably unlikely--or the server sees a client request different from the same request coming from the server.  Try turning debug logging on for the firewall.

Comment: Daniel I check the firewall settings it is all okay. Still facing this issue.

Comment: OK, so you said that in wireshark, the server is sending an access reject.  For the simple https `get` you are sending, which works on the server, you are not putting in a password or client key (that comes later).  If there was, your requests on the server would also be rejected.  So server is rejecting based on either the network port the request is coming in on, or the MAC or IP address of the request.  If you use wireshark again, can you see your https://ip_address/ request to make sure it is coming in the designated port and not just making a loopback request?

Comment: If you can see both requests (from client and from server) in wireshark going to the same network port, then look for differences, but I suspect it is going to be nothing more than MAC/IP addresses.  That leads back to the domain controller not wanting to service certain addresses.